# How to Poweroff a Virtual Machine using Oracle VirtualBox Java API?

Tags: java, virtualbox

I'm learnig to use VirtualBox Java API, but the documentation is not good.

My code:

```
VirtualBoxManager virtualBoxManager = VirtualBoxManager.createInstance(null);

IVirtualBox vbox = virtualBoxManager.getVBox();
List<IMachine> machines= vbox.getMachines();

for (IMachine m : machines) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + m.getName() + " OS: " + m.getOSTypeId());
    virtualBoxManager.startVm(m.getName(), null, 7000); //Starting a VM
}

virtualBoxManager.cleanup();
```

How I stop a VM?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727605/how-to-control-the-virtualbox-vms-through-java-code

Comment: See https://github.com/enexusde/vboxjws/wiki/Code-Examples

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.virtualbox_5_0.*;

public class VirtualboxVMStop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String machineName = "Centos_1";
        String url = "http://localhost:18083";
        String user = "test";
        String passwd = "test";

        VirtualBoxManager mgr = VirtualBoxManager.createInstance(null);
        mgr.connect(url, user, passwd);

        // Get the virtual machine you need to connect to.
        IVirtualBox vbox = mgr.getVBox();
        IMachine machine = vbox.findMachine(machineName);

        ISession session = null;
        IProgress prog;

        // Determine the status of the virtual machine.
        MachineState state = machine.getState();
        System.out.println(state);

        if (MachineState.Running == state) {
            session = mgr.getSessionObject();
            machine.lockMachine(session, LockType.Shared);
            prog = session.getConsole().powerDown();
            prog.waitForCompletion(10000);
            session.unlockMachine();
        } else {
            System.out.println(machineName+" is PoweredOff!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a description explaining what you did please

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13232680)